# Force react proxy to proxy certain endpoint even with accept: text/html

Tags: reactjs, proxy

React proxy only proxy request without Accept: text/html in the header (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/). But there is a redirect to my proxy server that have Accept: text/html in the header that I can't control. Is there a way to configure react proxy to for redirect certain endpoint no matter what in the Accept header. Like

```
always_redirect : /api/registration/confirmation
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. To proxy non AJAX calls through react, you will need to install `http-proxy-middleware` and configure proxy manually.

First install `http-proxy-middleware`  in your react app

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
```

Then create `src/setupProxy.js` file with below configuration

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8080',
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Now simply start the application and you will see that non AJAX calls (php etc) are also being proxied correctly.

**Note:** Remove the proxy configuration from `package.json` file before configuring it manually with `http-proxy-middleware` otherwise the proxy won't work correctly if defined at both the places